# Issue on adding @types/react-notification-system in react/typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-notifications

I have used react-notification-system in React+Javascript, when I tried in React+Typescript it throws error as

```
Type 'ReactInstance' is not assignable to type 'null'
Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'null'
```

in the line included in `componentDidMount()`

Patientadd.tsx

```
import * as NotificationSystem from 'react-notification-system';
class Patientadd extends React.Component<any, IState> {

public componentDidMount=()=>{
    this._notificationSystem = this.refs.notificationSystem;
  }

  _notificationSystem: null;
  _addNotification=(event)=> {
      this._notificationSystem.addNotification({
        message: event.message,
        title:event.title,
        level: event.level,
        autoDismiss: event.autoDismiss,
      });
  }
  public render() {
    return (
        <div className="App2">
          <NotificationSystem ref="notificationSystem" />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your import is bad, I think it is: import NotificationSystem from 'react-notification-system'

Comment: Module ../node_modules/@types/react-notification-system/index has no default export @kornflexx

Comment: Did you tried to console.log its value ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import * as NotificationSystem from 'react-notification-system';

export default class Patientadd extends React.Component<any, IState> {
  notificationSystem = React.createRef();

  addNotification = (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const notification = this.notificationSystem.current;
    notification.addNotification({
      message: event.message,
      title:event.title,
      level: event.level,
      autoDismiss: event.autoDismiss,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App2">
        <button onClick={this.addNotification.bind(this)}>Add notification</button>
        <NotificationSystem ref={this.notificationSystem} />
      </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: throws error <on line>  notificationSystem: React.createRef();     as ===> "(13,38): error TS1005: ';' expected"      &&&&                                                                                                           ,changed the line  notificationSystem= React.createRef(); ==>"error (19,21): Parameter 'event' implicitly has an 'any' type"     <on line>    "addNotification = event => {

Comment: Error: Object is possibly 'null'.    <on Line>   const notification = this.notificationSystem.current;

Comment: Try to use https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator

Comment: this.notificationSystem!.current